Another request for help in removing a glass cover over a halogen bulb that needs replacing
I have moved into a new apartment with Italian wall halogen lights, once of which now needs replacing. The halogen bulb is protected by a glass cover which has no obvious method of removal. I have provided links to photos below. I have tried pulling off the entire thing, and inserting a screwdriver under the spring clips at either end of the glass cover, but nothing budges.
I believe the light is made by Keria, but there is nothing similar on their current website so it may be some years old.
Thanks for you suggestions.



And once you’ve gotten the cover and old bulb out, remember: don’t touch the new bulb with your bare fingers… oils/ contamination can cause the bulb to shatter.

This is a good chance to upgrade the fittings to LED, saves the cost of a halogen lamp unless you already bought it.

Do you own or rent your apartment? If you rent, there is a potential frame challenge in that the landlord should be your first stop for maintenance questions (even if you ultimately do the maintenance yourself).

The glass and the two brackets are meant to be one piece. They need to be pulled straight up. The two brackets grasp around the two sockets. Try lifting the brackets with a slotted screwdriver agaist the bottom of the bracket, not on the glass. Then use the screwdriver under the top tab against the metal, not the glass. The bulb is spring loaded. After replacing it, the glass and two brackets gets carefully pushed back down over the two sockets.

First do what is probably the intended thing: hold the glass firmly near the ends between thumb and fingers on both sides, use rubber gloves if it helps, and try hard to pull it off.   The metal clips holding it to the bulb socket should pop off. Try rocking it side to side.  If that doesn't work ...
Use a screwdriver in one of the two noted locations (green), or both, or the similar one on the opposite side, should help to dislodge the horseshoe-shaped bracket (yellow) from the bulb socket.  The glass cover and the two brackets should come off together.
If THAT doesn't work,loosen the nut holding the bulb socket on (right side of the photo).  This will allow you to jiggle the socket, which may loosen the grip of the horseshoe bracket.  You'll have to feel your way to being both forceful and non-destructive.  And you may fail.
If even that doesn't work, this is desperate but use a screwdriver in the red location to bend the little metal flap up.  This may destroy the bracket or the glass.  It's a step to try before throwing the whole thing away.


If you say "do this first" in the last paragraph, it suggests you should put that first in the answer rather than tacking it on the end.

@nanoman ya.  Done.
